# ClientAliveInterval to prevent ssh session freezing / disconnecting?

Tags: ssh, sshd

After having my VPS upgraded to CentOs 5.5, I began to experience frozen / disconnected shell sessions if I had neglected them for a certain amount of time.  Very annoying.  The solution I found was to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and set the `ClientAliveInterval` to the desired number of seconds.  My understanding is that this essentially substitutes for activity from the client user (me) and so keeps the session from disconnecting.

Having initiated a shell session after making this minor change, I seem to be able to maintain a neglected session.  However, just because a thing seems to be working doesn't mean the best, or even correct, approach was necessarily taken.

Is there a better / different way to prevent a shell session from freezing?

Answer (score 0):

The `ClientAliveInterval` value can increase the sshd timeout, you can try the following command as well

```
echo "TMOUT=300 >> /etc/bashrc

echo "readonly TMOUT" >> /etc/bashrc

echo "export TMOUT" >> /etc/bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

No guarantees, but this is what I recently started using on the server. 10 seconds seems like a short time, but I don't trust my phone to keep the connection alive. I suppose you could increase the number of seconds till the problem starts again, then dial it back.

```
ClientAliveInterval 10
```

Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the client, sshd(8) will send a message through the encrypted channel to request a response from the client. The default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to the client.

```
ClientAliveCountMax 200
```

If it fails, keep trying for about 30 minutes. In other words, keep trying 200x, every 10 seconds. My logic could be flawed though, depending on what happens after 10 seconds. Assuming the client is quiet (like maybe I'm reading) does the "alive" message reset the max count if successful? Is inactivity considered failure? Or is failure a "no acknowledgement" of the alive message? Until I know the answer, I figure it's safe to repeat 200x.

Similar question here, and some decent recommendations...

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400427/when-to-use-clientaliveinterval-versus-serveraliveinterval